# Change CSS positioning method responsively, for only one axis?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-position

Hopefully these images I've prepared will explain sufficiently the challenge I've encountered.

In a responsive Bootstrap layout I'm working on there is a main content container and three follow-up paragraphs lined up below it. Each paragraph has a call-to-action button below it. The mobile alignment looks good, as they are all centered horizontally, in a vertical stack like this:

[image: Mobile alignment is centered and has no problems.]

In the desktop layout however, the three blue buttons get pushed to different heights because of varying paragraph lengths. Like so:

[image: Desktop layout: Buttons below the paragraphs are at varying heights.]

For clarity, here is the outcome I desire - buttons aligned to match the button of lowest position:

[image: The desired result: Buttons lined up to match the lowest one.]

I don't think I can solve this by positioning the buttons relative to a common div because that object's position will change completely in the mobile layout.

I thought maybe hiding the buttons using display:none when the browser window drops below a certain width and replacing them with others might be a viable solution, but it seems like bad semantics to have the same links appear twice in the HTML. (Would Google care?)

Another option I considered is fixing the height of the paragraph column divs and making the button position relative to the bottom of the divs, but then this seems to go against the principle of a fluid layout and might introduce new problems when the text is rendered in different fonts in different browsers. Can't have the paragraph text getting cropped or overlapped.

Have I stumbled upon something tricky or am I just failing to realize an obvious solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post online answering your question, check it out here `[http://jsbin.com/tunohe/1][1]`

Here's the HTMl,CSS & JavaScript code

```
.box2 > div {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
@media (min-width:992px) { 
    .box,
    .box2 > div {
        padding-bottom: 75px
    }
    .box .button,
    .box2 .button {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 15px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .box2 h3:first-child {
        margin-top: 0
    }
}



/* ============== RESPONSIVE EQUAL HEIGHTS  ========= */
/* Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows */
(function($){$.fn.equalHeight=function(){var heights=[];$.each(this,function(i,element){$element=$(element);var element_height;var includePadding=($element.css('box-sizing')=='border-box')||($element.css('-moz-box-sizing')=='border-box');if(includePadding){element_height=$element.innerHeight();}else{element_height=$element.height();}
heights.push(element_height);});this.css('height',Math.max.apply(window,heights)+'px');return this;};$.fn.equalHeightGrid=function(columns){var $tiles=this;$tiles.css('height','auto');for(var i=0;i<$tiles.length;i++){if(i%columns===0){var row=$($tiles[i]);for(var n=1;n<columns;n++){row=row.add($tiles[i+n]);}
row.equalHeight();}}
return this;};$.fn.detectGridColumns=function(){var offset=0,cols=0;this.each(function(i,elem){var elem_offset=$(elem).offset().top;if(offset===0||elem_offset==offset){cols++;offset=elem_offset;}else{return false;}});return cols;};$.fn.responsiveEqualHeightGrid=function(){var _this=this;function syncHeights(){var cols=_this.detectGridColumns();_this.equalHeightGrid(cols);}
$(window).bind('resize load',syncHeights);syncHeights();return this;};})(jQuery);



$(window).load(function() {
    $('.box').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
    $('.box2 > div').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
});



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="BSWP">
        <meta name="author" content="Diane Frierson">
        <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">

        <title>Bootstrap to Wordpress</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core  CSS -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- FontAwesome Icons -->

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="assets/css/mycustom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>


 <div class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="text-center">Equal Height Columns</h2>

   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 box">
          <h3 class="text-center">Newcomers Begin Here</h3>
    <p>You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive you personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel industry.
      <p class="button">
        <button type="button" class="center-block btn btn-success btn-lg">JOIN NOW</button></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 box">
          <h3 class="text-center">Newcomers Begin Here</h3>
    <p>You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive your own  personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel industry.</p>
      <p class="button">
        <button type="button" class="center-block btn btn-success btn-lg">JOIN NOW</button></p>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 box">
          <h3 class="text-center">Newcomers Begin Here</h3>
    <p>You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive your own.</p>
      <p class="button">
        <button type="button" class="center-block btn btn-success btn-lg">JOIN NOW</button></p>
    </div>

  </div>

   <hr>

  <h2 class="text-center">Equal Height Columns</h2>

   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 box2">
      <div>
          <h3 class="text-center">Newcomers Begin Here</h3>
    <p>You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive you personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel industry.
      <p class="button">
        <button type="button" class="center-block btn btn-success btn-lg">JOIN NOW</button></p>
    </div></div>

    <div class="col-md-4 box2">
      <div>
          <h3 class="text-center">Newcomers Begin Here</h3>
    <p>You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive your own  personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel industry.</p>
      <p class="button">
        <button type="button" class="center-block btn btn-success btn-lg">JOIN NOW</button></p>
    </div></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 box2">
          <div>
          <h3 class="text-center">Newcomers Begin Here</h3>
    <p>You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive your own.</p>
      <p class="button">
        <button type="button" class="center-block btn btn-success btn-lg">JOIN NOW</button></p>
    </div></div>

    <div class="col-md-4 box2">
      <div>
          <h3 class="text-center">Newcomers Begin Here</h3>
    <p>You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive you personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel industry.
      <p class="button">
        <button type="button" class="center-block btn btn-success btn-lg">JOIN NOW</button></p>
    </div></div>

    <div class="col-md-4 box2">
      <div>
          <h3 class="text-center">Newcomers Begin Here</h3>
    <p>You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive your own  personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel industry.</p>
      <p class="button">
        <button type="button" class="center-block btn btn-success btn-lg">JOIN NOW</button></p>
    </div></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 box2">
          <div>
          <h3 class="text-center">Newcomers Begin Here</h3>
    <p>You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive your own  personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel industry You will immediately earn 75% of paid commission, payable to you within 2 weeks of receipt. Upon registering, you immediately receive your own  personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel personalized website, with product and software training as well as mentoring. You will have at your fingertips all the tools necessary to immediately begin your business in the travel industry</p>
      <p class="button">
        <button type="button" class="center-block btn btn-success btn-lg">JOIN NOW</button></p>
    </div></div>     








  </div>   

</div>  




</body>
</html>





        <!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE JAVASCRIPT
             Place at the end of the document so the pages
             load faster!
        ======================================== -->

          <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
          <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
          <script src="assets/js/function.js"></script>

          <!-- TypeKit Fonts -->
          <script src="//use.typekit.net/ujd2dvf.js"></script>
          <script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! Thank you. Although for anyone else who comes across this I think Sam152's GitHub link is the one that will prove most useful as it actually explains what the code is doing. And the demo is more streamlined. https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows

Comment: I've implemented it and it's working perfectly. It's worth noting that no modification of the buttons' styling was necessary. I put the text above the buttons in their own divs with the class name specified in the javascript function. Since this equalizes the height of the paragraph divs the buttons below naturally follow at the correct height.

Answer (score 0):

```
On the Desktop
    1) Set a min-height for all the containers for that paragraph in CSS
    2) Set a height for the containers in CSS and make overflow:auto so it scrolls if it exceeds the height.(If you dont mind the scroll)
    3) Write a javascript snippet to calculate the max height among them and set that height to the containers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give a fixed height for the paragraph and make height auto in smaller devices like :

```
p{height:auto;} -->For mobile devices
p{height:200px;} -->For desktop
```